# What is the difference between javaee-api and javaee-web-api?

Tags: java, api

I realise these dependencies are required for compiling against Java servlet specification, and so on, but I'm not clear on the differences between them, and when I should use one as opposed to the other.

What is the difference between them? Is one a superset of the other?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: See [similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24239978/642706) with more answers.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `javaee-web-api` is supposed to support the [Java EE Web Profile](http://jaxenter.com/introducing-the-java-ee-web-profile-36201.html).

> Introduced in Java EE 6, the Web Profile radically streamlines the platform and enables the creation of a new dawn of lightweight, agile, compelling application servers with a laser focus on web application development.

However if you compare the two different jar files there is little that differs between them. I opened them up in 7-zip and these two screenshots shows the only (AFAIK) differences, namely that there is no support for JMS in the `javaee-web-api` **and** that the `xml` library seems to be larger in the `javaee-api`.

**`javaee-api`**

[image]

**`javaee-web-api`**

[image]

Comment: This is a bit misleading answer. You may see the right answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239978/java-ee-web-profile-vs-java-ee-full-platform