# javax:javaee-api-6.0 contains non-abstract classes with no method body

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, java-ee-7

I am fairly new to Java EE and when I look into the compiled code (I could not find the source code for javax:javaee-api-6.0), I notice this class.

```
package javax.servlet;

import java.util.EventObject;

public class ServletContextEvent extends EventObject
{
  public ServletContextEvent(ServletContext paramServletContext);

  public ServletContext getServletContext();
}
```

However, the same class in javax:javaee-api-7.0 is this.

```
package javax.servlet;

import java.util.EventObject;

public class ServletContextEvent extends EventObject
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -7501701636134222423L;

  public ServletContextEvent(ServletContext source)
  {
    super(source);
  }

  public ServletContext getServletContext()
  {
    return (ServletContext)super.getSource();
  }
}
```

The also happens to ServletException in the same package (there might be more, as I didn't go through each of them).

Assuming Java Decompiler gave me what the source code looks like, from a pure java grammar point of view, I can't understand why the 6.0 classes are not abstract (or, not interfaces).

**Question 1.**  Why are the classes in 6.0 not abstract or interfaces?

**Question 2.**  Why is the implementation changed in 7.0?  Did people realize the 6.0 version would cause trouble when you compile code with javaee-api?

The reason I ask is because I actually got compile errors when using javaee-web-api (which has similar classes as javaee-api, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16789020/842860)) in Intellij IDEA (12.1.4).  The error looks like this:

```
Internal error: (java.lang.ClassFormatError) Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletContextEvent
```

So **Question 3.**  Is there a way to avoid this in Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Did people realize the 6.0 version would cause trouble when you
>   compile code with javaee-api?

Yes, one of the problmes is that you cannot use those classes when running tests. See [this Arquillian FAQ](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/WhatsTheCauseOfThisExceptionJavalangClassFormatErrorAbsentCode) and [Adam Bien's blog post](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/trouble_with_crippled_java_ee).

> Is there a way to avoid this in Intellij IDEA?

See the links above. The solution is not specific to Intellij IDEA.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Seems the only solution is to use a concrete jar file that implements javaee-api, which is kind of clumsy.

Comment: It's also extremely annoying when generating metamodel classes for JPA Criteria queries. Compilation fails even though the JAR is provided, and you will be deploying the application to a running Java EE server. Interestingly, javaee-api-7 works correctly.

Comment: @IanEvans the javaee-api-7 does include the implementation.