# java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/jms/JMSException

Tags: java, maven, junit, jms, mockito

im getting the below issue when i run junit test cases, the class is as follow:;

public class RoeSubmissionBeanTest {

```
RoeSubmissionBean roeSubmissionBean;
ServiceActivation serviceAct = new ServiceActivation();
UpdateTimeResponse updateTimeResponse = new UpdateTimeResponse();
RoEUpdateSuccessfulDT roeUpdateSucces;
MessageIdentification msgID;
ExchangeFaultData faultMessage;
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception  {
```

//it failes on this line

```
    roeSubmissionBean = Mockito.mock(RoeSubmissionBean.class);
    serviceAct = Mockito.mock(ServiceActivation.class);
    updateTimeResponse =  Mockito.mock(UpdateTimeResponse.class);
    roeUpdateSucces =  Mockito.mock(RoEUpdateSuccessfulDT.class);
    doCallRealMethod().when(roeSubmissionBean).sendMessage(roeUpdateSucces, msgID, faultMessage);
}
```

and the main methods is

public class RoeSubmissionBean {

```
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RoeSubmissionBean.class);
private JMSSender sender = new JMSSender(RoeSubmissionBean.class);
```

}

i tried some questions here that i have to put dependency in POM, but still getting same error

Error:
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/jms/JMSException

```
    {  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:349)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getMethods(Enhancer.java:422)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:457)
```

}

Comment: verify that you do not have javaee-api imported multiple times in you pom, remove it or put it at the end of dependencies

Comment: i only have 1 entry for javaee-api and i have moved it to the end now, still getting the same error  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

Comment: try by removing it, it is maybe imported with another dependency

Comment: Here is the answer (Already linked in related section) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125115/javaxjavaee-api-6-0-contains-non-abstract-classes-with-no-method-body

Answer (score 0):

This exception indicate you don`t have class in your classpath. Verify your dependencies in pom.xml file and the scope of them.

Another error is sometimes jar the in your local repository jar was corrupted and the bytecode of class not present.

The class javax.jms.JMSException can be find in dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```